# What causes neovim ram problem with typescript?

Tags: typescript, neovim, tsserver

I've been using lunarvim to programming in typescript, so, i'm using tsserver + prettier + eslint...
I have 12GB ram.
(Intel i5 10210u)
SSD

With brave, discord and lunarvim opened, my ram monitor show about 45%-60% of usage.

At sometime, my ram usage just jump to 75%, 80%, 90%, 95% (in a matter of seconds) til my system crash totally.
In vscode i'm not facing this problem and with brave and discord oponed aside, my ram usage dont hit even 70%...

Lunarvim install and setup tsserver automatically, my others configurations are:

```
local formatters = require "lvim.lsp.null-ls.formatters"
  formatters.setup {
        { command = "prettier", filetypes = { "typescript", "javascript" } },
  }
```

```
local linters = require "lvim.lsp.null-ls.linters"
linters.setup {
    { command = "eslint", filetypes = { "typescript", "javascript" } },
}
```

I have also try neovim with native lsp and coc. Both cause the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens to me when I use Astro. Multiple instances of eslint servers are created and then they are not responding so I have to kill all of them. This doesn't seem to be a problem where I am developing the project with multiple eslint rules. But here in the Astro project, I use standard guidelines for tsx/ts and Astro guidelines for "*.astro" files.
[image]